# Spring-Social: Have my bean supersede the one created by autoconfiguration

Tags: spring-boot, spring-social

I've been following some tutorials on how to get a website to use spring-security and spring-social for authentication. I got the whole basic thing working. The code includes a bean to define the `ConnectionFactoryLocator` as follows:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator() {
    ConnectionFactoryRegistry registry = new ConnectionFactoryRegistry();

    registry.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(
        environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.appId"),
        environment.getProperty("spring.social.facebook.appSecret")));

    return registry;
}
```

So, this all worked fine until I wanted to do something different in this bean and realized it wasn't being used at all. The spring-boot output showed:

`Overriding bean definition for bean 'connectionFactoryLocator' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=true; factoryBeanName=securityConfiguration; factoryMethodName=connectionFactoryLocator; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [myapp/configuration/SecurityConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfiguration; factoryMethodName=connectionFactoryLocator; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/social/config/annotation/SocialConfiguration.class]]`

I read online and came to understand the concept of autoconfiguration and the fact that it can be enabled without explicitly requesting it in spring-boot.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

According to this site the configuration should be non-invasive and defining my own bean should make the automatic one "back down". This, however, is not happening in this case.

I tried adding the property `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfiguration.class`

but the override still happens. Running the app with debug shows the exclusion properly

```
Exclusions:
-----------

    org.springframework.social.config.annotation.SocialConfiguration.class
```

but the autoconfigured bean is the one that prevails. The last interesting thing I see is that if I remove the definition of my own bean the app doesn't start anymore complaining that there are no matches for that bean. This last thing happens even without the exclusion.

I have also attempted to change the names of the id/secret properties from the spring-social standard to my own names and that had no effect other than having the app not work properly when running on the autoconfigured bean.

I realize there may be a fundamental spring concept I am not quite catching but I've read around and cant' seem to figure out what it may be.

Thanks.

Comment: I also tried the @Primary annotation on my bean, no effect.

Comment: Continued reading suggested the possibility of a dependency issue (the @Autowired property is in the same class as the bean method). Even though it didn't look like a potential for a cyclic dependency I tried moving the bean method out to a separate class and the same thing still happens, it gets overriden by the standard version from autoconfiguration.